# Does the Oracle JVM on macOS use hardened runtime and library validation?

Tags: java, macos, code-signing

I have a JNI .dylib that I want to distribute in a macOS installer .pkg, along with the library for which the JNI .dylib is providing a wrapper and associated tools. To pass notarization, all libraries and executables included in the package must be signed.

When I sign the JNI .dylib with my developer id, `java.lang.System.loadLibrary` fails to load it, telling me that no such library was found in `java.library.path`. If the library is adhoc signed then `loadLibrary` succeeds. The most likely explanation I have found is that the JVM is using the macOS hardened runtime and therefore library validation which means that because my library is signed by a different "team" than the JVM the load fails.
Seemingly contradicting that is that fact that when the JNI .dylib is adhoc signed, and so is loaded, the library for which it is a wrapper, on which it has a dependency and which is fully signed by me, is successfully loaded.

I want to confirm about the JVM to either rule this in or out as the problem, hence my question. I'm using Oracle JavaSE JDK 18.

If this is the case, is there any workaround to be able to get `loadLibrary` to load a fully signed library? If there is not I will have to see if my .pkg can pass notarization with this library merely adhoc signed.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If it only accepts libraries signed by the same certificate as the JVM it wouldn't accept 'ad-hoc' signing. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is not using library validation. Whether it uses the hardened runtime with validation turned off or does not use the hardened runtime I don't know.

The problem with my "signed" .dylib was not that it was signed but that an LC_RPATH pointing at the library location in my build tree had been removed by the signing macro I was using. That is why I was getting library "not found". I fixed it so the library binary now has 2 LC_RPATH commands, one adding just
`@rpath`, the other the library's eventual install location. Now I can load the library as expected both when it is signed and when it is not.